# Tracking outbound Email Bounce Processing using SMTP protocol

Tags: outbound-email

I have set up a mail server in IIS using a `SMTP relay` for the Tridion Outbound Email feature.It is working fine to deliver the mails to the respective contacts. But the bounce Processing is not working properly.

In the sdl documents it has been mentioned to use either `IMAP` or `POP3` protocol.Is there any chance to configure the Bounce Processing using `SMTP` protocol for tracking the undelivered mails.

Or do I need to set any `Tracked links` in the TBB for the undelivered mails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't check for bounces on SMTP because the protocol is only used to *send* e-mails. You don't have an inbox to check for messages in.

Instead, you'll want to use either IMAP or POP3 and point it to the inboxes for the reply and bounce addresses that you use in your Mailings.

For bounce detection to work fully, you need to have at least one tracked link in your Mailing. Without a tracked link, only the Contact will be updated - the statistics on the Mailing are not (since it can't know the Mailing that was sent).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, How can I add one tracked link in my mailer. Do I have to add the parameter  @@GetLinkTrackingURL@@ to the links in dwt, can you please share one example

Comment: Yes, either that or you can track all links automatically by selecting that option on the "post processing" TBB (requires that the output is valid XHTML, though).